# rotate between abbrev expansions?

Tags: abbrev

**Q:** is there a way to rotate between multiple expansions bound to the same abbrev?

I'm experimenting with `abbrev-mode`, and I have some abbreviations that I'd like to use for different expansions of the same abbrev.

For example, I often use the abbreviation "st" for "sometimes", but occasionally use it to mean "such that".  I'd like to know if there's a way to bind the "st" abbrev to produce "sometimes" as its default expansion, but allow me to select "such that" as a secondary expansion.

Sound goofy?  Here's how it's working in my mind.  Let's say I've got a hypothetical command `expand-abbrev-and-rotate` bound to the `tab` key and `*` representing point:

1. some text st*`tab` => some text sometimes*
2. some text sometimes*`tab` => some text such that*
3. some text such that*`tab` => some text sometimes*
4. ... and so forth, rotating among a short list of possible expansions (2 in this case)

Does `abbrev-mode` have anything that could approximate this behavior?  I've been peeking at the internals and can imagine a way to implement it, but wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I haven't used `abbrev`, but from [what I read](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html), isn't the behavior of Dynamic Abbrev what you want; continuously hitting `M-/` to cycle through the abbrev expansions?

Comment: @kaushalmodi: I, in turn, haven't used `dabbrev`, but it doesn't look like it.  My understanding of `dabbrev` is that it scans previous text in the buffer to create the abbrev options, whereas I'm looking to set the options for a particular abbrev, irrespective of prior text, in a set order.

Comment: Exactly, `dabbrev` will propose you expansions based in previous inserted text in the buffer. Not what we're looking for. Yes, I'll be interested by the behaviour you describe Dan.

Comment: @Dan If you *do* end up implementing it manually, you might want to look into how `hippie-expand` achieves this exact effect.

Comment: @Malabarba: thanks for the suggestion -- I'll look more closely into `hippie-expand` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yasnippet can do what you want. Either a shortcut key-binding or a prefix substring can expand to a particular snippet. And each snippet can present a list of options via yas-choose-value.

Here is an example snippet based on your example:

## -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-

## name: st

## key: st

## binding: direct-keybinding

## --

${1:$$(yas-choose-value '("sometimes" "such that"))}

Now I can type "st" and hit the yas-trigger-key (defaults to TAB but I have set mine to SHIFT-TAB), and I am prompted for a selection between the 2 possibilities.

In my .init.el file I have the following:

`(setq yas-prompt-functions '(
                             yas-ido-prompt
                             yas-x-prompt`

which by default uses ido as the selection method.  If you are on x-windows, you can use the x-prompt for a nice graphical popup.  There are other selection methods as well.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide an example here of a snippt that presents a set of options.